# Prepopulate "from:" field on outlook email using commands

Tags: command-line, outlook, office365, office-automation

I've followed different tutorials about prepopulating an email using outlook, and I've been successful on filling the "To:", "CC:", "Subject:" and the body.

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m test@gmail.com?v=1
&cc=otherEmail@gmail.com
&subject=hello
&body=hi%20there
```

The point is, I would want to change the "From:" field, since I have 3 different accounts on my Outlook. I was wondering if there are some command to do that.

I didnt find anything about how to do it, I tried this but didnt work:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m test@gmail.com?v=1
&from=secondaryAccount@gmail.com
&cc=otherEmail@gmail.com
&subject=hello
&body=hi%20there
```

This also didnt work:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /profile=secondaryAccount@gmail.com
/m test@gmail.com?v=1
&cc=otherEmail@gmail.com
&subject=hello
&body=hi%20there
```

Im using Outlook installed on my local PC, Office365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to automate Outlook to set the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property available in the Outlook object model. Not all properties are available in the command line unfortunately. Here is a VBA macro which shows hot to set up the property:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

Also you may find the [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-other-office-applications) article helpful.